# how to get the certificate of an SMTP server in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Recently I was trying to verify a SMTP server's certificate by using the Java mail and Apache commons email framework, but I didn't get any clue of just verify the cert of the SMTP server (ssl or tls used) without sending any message/mail.I guess it may use the **SSLSocket** to do this, but I just get A SSLException said 'the message should be plain' , not a Certificate Exception (I expected).any idea?

Edited:(Use a sslsocket.connect)
I really get a certificate exception by using the follow code

```
        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory  
            .getDefault();  
    SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("localhost", 9999);  //9999 is the SMTP SSL port
    //this really throws a exception.
    s.startHandshake();
    System.out.println("ok");
```

The exception is :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
```

I think this can help me to dertermine whether the certificate is valid or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "smtp", not "snmp".

If you got a "should be plain" error, that means you connected to the plain text port instead of the SSL port.

If you just want to verify that the certificate is valid, without logging in, you should use a [SSLSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) and see if you can connect without getting an exception.

If you want to verify that the certificate is valid and that the authentication information is valid, you can use [Transport.connect](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Service.html#connect-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).